# How pass the current data with converter?

Tags: xamarin.forms

How can i send the current element of my Actors list to my converter? and as well i need pass a parameter with  ConverterParameter

```
<ListView x:Name="Actors" ItemsSource="{Binding Actors}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.ContextActions>  
                        Source="" IsVisible="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource ListConverter}, ConverterParameter={Binding ActorCurrent}}"}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

this Actor exist  in my view movel, i need to pass as parameter

```
private Actor _actorCurrent;
        public Actor ActorCurrent
        {
            get => _actorCurrent;
            set
            {
                _actorCurrent = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ActorCurrent);
            }
        }
```

i tried with dot, but dont work

```
IsVisible="{Binding . // in my Converter class i dont nothing
```

EDIT 1:

i have as well this

```
 public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
// i want to value = will be {Binding .,
// and parameter = will be ActorCurrent
// then i want to compare value with parameter and return a bool

    }
```

**Or can i use triggers?**

```
<DataTrigger TargetType="Image" Binding="{Binding Name}" Value="{Binding ActorCurrent.name}">
```

Comment: You want to binding IsVisible with ActorCurrent or set ActorCurrent as ConverterParameter? If you want to set ActorCurrent as ConverterParameter, which property would you like to bind to IsVisible ?

Comment: "." is the correct way to pass the current context.  You will have to cast it in the converter because it is an object.  "don't work" is not a helpful description of the problem you are having when you try that.  And please take the time to clean up your code, it is incomplete/incorrect syntax and unreadable.  Please use a [mcve] if you want help.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT i edited my question see please

Comment: @Jason i edited my question see please!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> i want to value = will be {Binding .}
> ```

You can get the value in the Convert method, you have to know the type of your value first. You can add a breakpoint there to get the type of value:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{

    //if the type of value is Actor:
    Actor tempActor = value as Actor;

    //if the type of value is string:
    string tempStr = value as string

    return  "123";
}
```

> and `parameter = will be ActorCurrent`

Actually, you can't set binding to ConverterParameter as [ConverterParameter](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/4fd2d6b45b7f287433ea2bf52581d376a06b999f/Xamarin.Forms.Xaml/MarkupExtensions/BindingExtension.cs#L13) is not a BindableProperty.

There is a discussion about this problem in [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/404667/#Comment_404667) and you may find some idea there.

Comment: or can i use triggers?

Comment: No, I don't think you can use a trigger.

Comment: Ok, I will check it.

Comment: help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61333329/how-can-i-comunicate-my-app-with-viewmodel please

Comment: The type when you Subscribe is not right. Change it to  MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string>(typeof(App), "gotosleep", async (obj, item) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("HERE"); //never showed me
            });

Comment: BTW, is my answer in this question helps you? If so, please mark/upvote it.