# How can I communicate in my app with ViewModel?

Tags: xamarin.forms

How communicate in my app with my ViewModel?

I have this code, sleep and resume of my app

```cs
protected override void OnSleep()
{
    MessagingCenter.Send<App, string>(this, "gotosleep", "savedata");
}
```

in my ViewModel I subscribe to the message, but it does not work. My message is never displayed.

```cs
public MyViewModel()
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string>(this, "gotosleep", async (obj, item) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HERE"); 
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi , have you solved this ? If answer be helpful , remember to mark that when you have time :-) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `MyViewModel` in **ContentPage**, then `Subscribe` of **MessagingCenter** will work.

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    // Use model in Content Page 
    MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel();
}
```

**However**, I find this does not work on iOS device, but works on Android.

Here is the **Workaround** to solve this, you can pass the `ContentPage` as an attribute for **ViewModel** when initialiation.

```cs
public MyViewModel(MainPage mainPage)
{
    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string>(mainPage, "gotosleep", async (obj, item) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HERE"); 
        await mainPage.DisplayAlert("Message received", "arg=" + item, "OK");
    });
}
```

In **ContentPage**, modify as follows:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    
    // Use model in Content Page 
    MyViewModel viewModel = new MyViewModel(this);
}
```

iOS effect:

[image]

Android effect:

[image]